# Does Vimeo delete basic accounts that have not been used for a full year?

Tags: vimeo

[This Page](http://vimeo.com/help/faq/vimeo-membership/basic-accounts#will-my-account-ever-be-deleted) says regarding Vimeo basic accounts (i.e. free accounts):

> We consider accounts that have not been used for a full year to be
>   inactive, and we reserve the right to remove inactive accounts.

Does Vimeo actually delete accounts that have not been used for a full year?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as already stated in the link, Vimeo deletes accounts and all uploaded videos for accounts classified as "Inactive". There is no way to gain those vidoes back. This is a common practice followed by many free hosting sites and servers.

Comment: Ok thanks,  I didn't know whether Vimeo actually enforces this policy.

Comment: Yep I was just waiting for other answers in case!